# What are the roles of IANA and ICANN in relation to domain names?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, top-level-domains, icann

I am aware that IANA is a department of ICANN, but how are their roles divided?

IANA should allocate IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to RIR's, allocate AS number ranges to RIR's and administrates the root DNS servers (`[a-m].root-servers.net`) among other things.

What is left for ICANN? Introducing new TLD's. Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers* ([ICANN](https://www.icann.org/)) is a non-profit organisation responsible for the root-level infrastructure, policy and governance of the Internet. Principally they:

- Work closely with *Domain Name Registries* that have chosen to enter into a contract with ICANN for governance, technical assistance and dispute resolution etc. (It is not mandatory for registries to come under ICANN, for example .edu and .gov are independently governed).
- Accredit *Domain Name Registrars* to allocate Domain Names to organisations and individuals for the Domain Name Registries with which ICANN have a contract in place.

  ICANN --> Registry --> Registrar ( --> ISP )

They have a subsidiary organisation, *Internet Assigned Numbers Authority* ([IANA](http://www.iana.org/)) which is globally responsible for the management and coordination of:

- [IP addresses](http://www.iana.org/numbers) and addressing systems - allocating IP addresses (both IPv4 and IPv6) from the pools of unallocated addresses to *Regional Internet Registries* (RIR's) according to needs, ICANN's global policies, [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/) technical standards etc. There are 5 RIR's - AFRINIC (Africa Region), APNIC (Asia/Pacific Region), ARIN (North America Region), LACNIC (Latin America and some Caribbean Islands), RIPE NCC (Europe, the Middle East, and Central Asia). RIR's manage the allocation of IP addresses to *National Internet Registries* (NIR's), who manage the allocation to *Internet Service Providers* (ISP's).
- Autonomous System Numbers, which are used by ISP's for routing Internet traffic, and allocated through the same channels as IP addresses.
- Protocol Assignments - maintaining the official technical standards as implemented on the Internet, with reserved port numbers and protocol acronyms etc (published as a long list of RFC's).
- The DNS Root Zone - assignments of *Global Top-Level Domains* (gTLDs) and *Country-Code Top-Level Domains* (ccTLDs) to third-party *Domain Name Registries*. Also the DNSSEC Root Key Signing Key is managed by IANA.
- Registry service for .int and .arpa zones, which are not available for use by general public.

  IANA --> RIR --> NIR --> ISP